# AXIOS: is there a way to POST an object WITHOUT FormData?

Tags: javascript, axios

in the [axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#example), it shows that you can POST an object directly through the `data` parameter, thusly:

```js
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'someHandler.php',
  data: {
    id: 200,
    sox: 'blue'
})
```

what i want to know is if you can PASS AN OBJECT into that `data` parameter:

```js
myObj = {
  id: 200,
  sox: 'blue'
}
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'someHandler.php',
  data: myObj
)
```

the above DOESN'T WORK, though it seems to me it should seeing as it's going to be JSON-encoded anyway.  i've searched the docs, but can't find anything that answers this question.

i know that i can append `myObj` to a `formData` and pass it that way, but i want to know if i'm overlooking a simpler way.

Comment: Looks right to me. How do you know it _"doesn't work"_?

Comment: because the `$_POST` array in the PHP handler comes up empty every time.  but, i hear ya: it looks solid.

Comment: does it work without the object assignment? i mean does the first snippet work?

Comment: yep. works just fine.  my issue is i'm passing a large JSON object into it, so i'm not interested in manually entering the data.  nor can i, as it comes in from other functions.

Comment: @WhiteRau — "because the $_POST array in the PHP handler comes up empty every time" — PHP doesn't support populating `$_POST` with JSON

Comment: You're posting JSON though so neither example above will populate PHP's `$_POST` variable. For that, you want `$json = file_get_contents("php://input");`

Comment: For the post data to be read via `$_POST`, you will need to use `FormData()`. The only way to read the object you're posting in your code is via `"php://input"` as aptly pointed out by @Phil.

Comment: okay.  that's what i wanted to know.  the JSON is sent by axios.  i'm just passing an object into axios.  perhaps i wasn't clear there.  the JSON is going to the PHP handler via axios.  the function is just passing objects to axios.